# HTML button vs jQuery (or js) to handle click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any reason to use the html button vs just using jQuery (or js) to handle click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *only* want to handle click events, then it doesn't matter.

If you want to handle a button being activated, then you can't simulate that by simply binding a click event on any kind of element. A button isn't only activated by clicking it, you can for example activate it by using the tab key to move focus to it, and press space. (Exact function may differ between browsers.)

You should try to use HTML elements that were designed for the action that you want to use, even if you take over everything with JavaScript. They not only look and react in a specific way, people who for example uses screen readers rely on being able to navigate pages in other ways than pointing and clicking.

Answer (score -1):

The HTML button tag will render as a button element, not just text.  It will actually look like a button.  The functionality would be the same (click and handle with JS), but the button has the advantage of looking like and behaving (pressing in on click) like a button.